# counting Div on a DOM element

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me understand why this below is not working? I would like to get true if an element has more than 5 divs in it.

```
var hasMorethanFiveDiv = function(domElement, divCounter) {
  // div counter variable(divcounter)
  divCounter = divCounter || 0;

  // if the current node has div
  if(domElement.tagName === "DIV"){
    divCounter++;
  }
  //iterate over children nodes
  for(var i=0; i<domElement.children.length; i++){  
    // invoke hasMorethanFiveDiv on a child element.
    hasMorethanFiveDiv(domElement.children[i], divCounter);
  }
  //return true if divCounter is bigger than 5
  return divCounter >= 5;
};
```

Comment: you aren't capturing the returned value inside the for loop

Comment: This would work for nested divs with changes like in here: http://jsbin.com/xuwakipili/edit

Comment: @ignacykasperowicz. good job.

Comment: @GinacyKasperowicz. thanks that helps. but what about not nested divs. like this http://jsbin.com/catamuzawa/edit it seems not working on this.

Answer (score 1):

It is this line :

```
hasMorethanFiveDiv(domElement.children[i], divCounter);
```

divCounter is not passed by reference but by value. This mean that if divCounter was modified in the function, it isn't return updated.

```js
// Variable are sent by value
var value = 1;

var addValue = function(arg) {
 arg++;   // arg value is now 2, but only for the scope of this function
}

addValue(value);
alert(value); // alert 1 NOT 2...


// Objects are sent by reference
var obj = {
 value: 1
}

var addValue2 = function(arg) {
 arg.value++;
}

addValue2(obj);

alert(obj.value); // alert 2
```

**A working example :**

```js
var hasMorethanFiveDiv = function(domElement) {
  //return true if divCounter is bigger than 5
  var objCounter = {counter: 0};
  divCounter(domElement, objCounter);
  return objCounter.counter >= 5;
};

var divCounter = function(domElement, objCounter) {
  // div counter variable(divcounter)
  
  // if the current node has div
  if(domElement.tagName === "DIV"){
    objCounter.counter++;
  }
  //iterate over children nodes
  for(var i=0; i<domElement.children.length; i++){  
    // invoke hasMorethanFiveDiv on a child element.
    divCounter(domElement.children[i], objCounter);
  }

}
alert(hasMorethanFiveDiv(document.getElementById("main1")));
alert(hasMorethanFiveDiv(document.getElementById("main2")))
```

```html
<div id="main1">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div><div></div><div></div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
<div id="main2">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, aprovent. this helped.